# Compare input to every id and output the closest matching one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making basic search on my website. When you type into the search it automatically compares the input against every element-id in the document. When it finds a match it scrolls to the matched element. As of now the search works only when you input the exact id (excluding case-sensitivity and spaces). 
Here is my JQuery code:

```
$('#search-box').focus(function() {
    $('#search-box').keyup(function () {
        var x = $('#search-box').val().replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
            if ($("#" + x).length !== 0) {
                navbarHeight = $('#fixed-navbar').height();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+x).position().top - window.navbarHeight}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

I think, I've tried everything starting from .match() to using plugins like List.js.

Is there a way to compare inputed text to id's and output the first matching one? Tolerance modifier would be neat but not required.

Comment: _I've tried everything starting from .match() to using plugins like List.js_ Well, what did or didn't work?

Comment: @Mathletics I think it's pretty safe to say that nothing the OP tried worked (otherwise why ask the question here?)

Comment: Consider using similar_text (http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) for the 'tolerance modifier' you mentioned.

Comment: @Greg Looks good but I think same thing can be done in javascript. It's not the main problem. By further searching I now think that I have to add every div with id to an array and go from there. That was my initial plan but I thought that I was overcomplicating, like I usually do.

Comment: @Elvegirl, my mistake, I didn't read carefully enough!@

Comment: @neuronaut no no no. I mean did it throw an error? Do something unexpected? "I could not solve the problem with this tool" is __not__ the same as "this tool cannot solve the problem."

Comment: @Mathletics I didn't find anything that would solve my problem out of the box. The List.js was close but the only thing was that it only worked with an array. I found a piece of code that will put every div id with a beginning of my choice (so I can only get the id's I need) to an array. Haven't tried it yet though. By saying "I think, I've tried everything..." I mean that "I'm inexperienced and I don't know what I'm supposed to do". Does that clear things up?

Comment: "closest-matching one"—you need an algorithm that determines the "closeness" of one string to another. Do you accept differences in the start and/or in the end? Do you have penalties based on differences in terms of length, bit character, unicode, ascii character...? Do you penalise if part of the query matches the search term, or part of the search term matches the query? It's a vague question, with too many answers possible. An example similarity algorithm would be the [Smith-Waterman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith–Waterman_algorithm)—among many others.

Comment: @Terry Thank you for your input! This project isn't all that serious, therefore the solution I came up with works fine for me.

Comment: FYI you can provide your own answer; it doesn't make sense to post your answer as an update to _the question_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### My solution:

```
// Searches automatically for first matching id

var idArray = $("div[id^='x-']")        // find spans with ID attribute
    .map(function() { return this.id; })// convert to set of IDs
    .get();                             // convert to instance of Array (optional)

navbarHeight = $('#fixed-navbar').height();

console.log(idArray);

$('#search-box').keyup(function () {

    for (var i=0; i<idArray.length; i++) {

        var input = $('#search-box').val().replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
        matched = idArray[i].match(new RegExp(input));

        if (matched !== null) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+ idArray[i]).position().top - window.navbarHeight});
            console.log('Matched part: ' + matched);
            break;
        };

        if (matched == undefined) {
            matched = [];
            matched.length = 0;
        };
    };
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocfur1wx/).

*(thx for help guys /s)*

**Final thoughts:**

I didn't add the tolerance variable but it's easy enough (compared to this IMO). 
Also, I may add so that it stats to search only from the beginning of the id (because people usually start typing the beginning of the word) but then the "search anywhere in the name" functionality won't work.

Edit: Finally managed to make it work the way I asked to. Code almost rewritten and updated.